# Lagrangian in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, field-theory, path-integral

Are the Lagrangians used in QFT operators or classical object?

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, the action (Lagrangian$^1$ density) in the [path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) are functionals (functions), respectively, as opposed to operators. This is a consequence of how the path-integral formalism is derived from the [operator formulation](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=&as_epq=operator+formulation) (by inserting infinitely many completeness relations).

The action & Lagrangian density usually don't depend on Planck's constant $\hbar$, and are therefore classical in that sense.

--

$^1$ It should perhaps be stressed that there also exist Hamiltonian path integral formulations.

Comment: Ok but since the fields are operator and Hamiltonian, function of fields, is an operator.. why can't I use the same stupid argument for Lagrangian?

Comment: I updated the answer.